# Add column to R dataframe that is length of string in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

This should be EASY but I can't figure it out and search didn't help.  I'd like to add a column to a dataframe that is just the length of the strings in another column.

So say I have a data frame of names like such:

```
   Name    Last
1  John     Doe
2 Edgar     Poe
3  Walt Whitman
4  Jane  Austen
```

I'd like to append a new column with the string length of, say, the last name, so it would look like:

```
   Name    Last  Length
1  John     Doe  3
2 Edgar     Poe  3
3  Walt Whitman  7
4  Jane  Austen  6
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `nchar`. `df$Length = nchar(df$Last)`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  I get the error "'nchar()' requires a character vector".  Looks like nchar() operates on a char vector, but not a column of char vectors.  I need something along the lines of "apply the function nchar on each cell in the column, and add return values to new column"

Comment: You probably just imported your data as factors. Use `df$Length <- nchar(as.character(df$Last))`

Comment: You probably have the column as factor. as @MrFlick.

Comment: sweet!  that was the trick.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_count` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
df1$Length <- str_count(df1$Last)
df1$Length
[1] 3 3 7 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by the length, based on column, then do the following:

```
library(dplyr) 

df<- df %>% 
  filter(nchar(Last) <= 3)
```